# I am accepting User data via Form, I want to add System Date and Time in my SQL Database, how should I do it using JAVA?

Tags: java, mysql, dao

Here is my DAO Implementation.
How should I insert Timestamp and Date in my Sql database. ?
I don't want the user to enter the timeand date , it should be automatically set according to the systems current date and time.

```
    @Override
    public void saveOrUpdate(Contact contact) {
        if (contact.getId() > 0) {
            // update
            String sql = "UPDATE contact SET name=?, email=?, address=?, "
                        + "telephone=? WHERE contact_id=?";
            jdbcTemplate.update(sql, contact.getName(), contact.getEmail(),
                    contact.getAddress(), contact.getTelephone(), contact.getId());
        } else {
            // insert
            String sql = "INSERT INTO contact (name, email, address, telephone)"
                        + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
            jdbcTemplate.update(sql, contact.getName(), contact.getEmail(),
                    contact.getAddress(), contact.getTelephone());
        }

    }
```

Comment: make some effort to change your code, what you have posted shows no effort what so ever

Comment: You have to first add a column in your table to keep the date-time data. Use `ALTER TABLE` command. Then update your java code to reflect the same

Comment: First thing that comes in mind: Simply add new Date() to your field and import from util.sql.Date. Also generate getter for that field

Comment: @Ab Sin I want to know the java code.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately mysql has date/time functions, so a possible solution is:

```
  @Override
public void saveOrUpdate(Contact contact) {
    if (contact.getId() > 0) {
        // update
        String sql = "UPDATE contact SET name=?, email=?, address=?, "
                    + "telephone=?, timestamp=NOW() WHERE contact_id=?";
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, contact.getName(), contact.getEmail(),
                contact.getAddress(), contact.getTelephone(), contact.getId());
    } else {
        // insert
        String sql = "INSERT INTO contact (name, email, address, telephone, timestamp)"
                    + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())";
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, contact.getName(), contact.getEmail(),
                contact.getAddress(), contact.getTelephone());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this adds the current system time in my database, but it changes when I edit the entry.
Can you guide me on how not to change the time every time I edit the record.

Comment: Just erase the timestamp field from the update clause again.

Answer (score 0):

In your Contact.java you first have to create a timestamp `import java.sql.Timestamp;`

```
    private Timestamp createdAt;
    @Column(name = "timestamp", length = 29)

    public Timestamp getCreatedAt() {
        return this.createdAt;
    }

    public void getCreatedAt(Timestamp createdAt) {
        this.createdAt= createdAt;
    }
```

Then in your DAO:

```
 @Override
public void saveOrUpdate(Contact contact) {
    if (contact.getId() > 0) {
        // update
        String sql = "UPDATE contact SET name=?, email=?, address=?, "
                    + "telephone=?, timestamp=? WHERE contact_id=?";
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, contact.getName(), contact.getEmail(),
                contact.getAddress(), contact.getTelephone(), contact.getCreatedAt(), contact.getId());
    } else {
        // insert
        String sql = "INSERT INTO contact (name, email, address, telephone, timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, contact.getName(), contact.getEmail(),
                contact.getAddress(), contact.getTelephone(), new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }

}
```

Check if this works.